# mapping a networkdrive in PS 2.0 with encoded credentials

Tags: powershell

I need to map drives and I have an encoded PW which I need to connect to DMZ drives.

I'm using the following code to map the drives:

```
[Byte[]]$key = (1..16)
$pw = Get-Content .\LocalAdminCred.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -key $key

# some other stuff

[string]$pwencoded = ConvertFrom-SecureString $pw -Key $key
$Map = New-Object -comobject Wscript.Network
$Map.MapNetworkDrive($_.letter,$_.path,$false,$_.username,$pwencoded)
```

What your eyes catches first is the `$pwencoded` Variable - I had to use a string for PW, that's why I needed to decode the `Secure.String` to a normal string, otherwise i would have had a type mismatch. now the problem is that `.MapNetworkDrive` needs the password in plain text like 'password' and mine is an encoded key and not a plain text.

To the question: Is it possible to use a encrypted password or even better a secure string to map my network drive this way? I really don't want to use plain text.

First I wanted to do the mapping with `New-PSDrive` but since the script must work for PS 2.0 I can't use that because the `-persist` Parameter doesn't exist there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the answer you're looking for but [Dave Wyatt](https://davewyatt.wordpress.com/about/) has a [few blog posts](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/11/24/saving-passwords-and-preventing-other-processes-from-decrypting-them/) about using [secure strings](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-Encryption-45709b87) and [credentials](http://powershell.org/wp/2014/02/01/revisited-powershell-and-encryption/).

> ... I also added an [-AsPlainText](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Add-optional-entropy-to-2519d9fd) switch to the ConvertFrom-SecureString command, in case you want to get the plain text back.

The only two ways I know how to map drives are to use plain text credentials. The only other way would be to run the script as an account that has permissions to the network location; that way you don't have to authenticate with a password.

Comment: Hi there, as far as I know and also `get-help convertfrom-securestring` says, there is no `-asplaintext` switch to this command

Comment: He made proxy functions to add the `-AsPlainText` parameter. [Here is a link to those proxy functions.](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Add-optional-entropy-to-2519d9fd)

Comment: cheers mate, this is perfect. when we update I will change `.MapNetworkDrive` to `New-PSDrive` until then I can live with plain text. thank you!